# mounting a cifs share for writing

Tags: permissions, mount, 22.04, fstab, cifs

I think I'm missing something obvious

I have a NAS (WD MyCloud Home). I can read and write to it from windows with no issues

I can mount it in ubuntu server using this command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USER,password=PASS //192.168.86.249/media /media/cifs/
```

I can read these files with any account
I can write to this mount as root
I can't write to the account as any other user

I've tryied chmod 777 on /media/cifs/ but that doesn't change any of the permissions
I've also tried chown to change ownership to another user and group. it won't take any changes

when I do ls -l I get this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Oct 10 23:46 cifs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  6 03:03 nas
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  6 16:27 zfs
```

if I unmount /media/cifs I am able to change the permissions and the owners but when I mount again it reverts the changes to root being the owner and permissions being drwxr-xr-x

Any suggestions welcome

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; nor clues as to what apps you're using when you try and write (*some apps run confined meaning they have reduced or different permissions; this is likely not your issue but you provided few specifics*). If the *file-system* is not POSIX compliant, the `chmod` may be unable to force changes & thus you need to handle that at `mount` time. The actual directories involved on your mount may also be useful

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Comment: Ultimately I want to use the mounted file system as a docker volume. but right now I'd settle to be able to touch a test file.

Comment: Read `man mount.cifs`, and use the `uid=` and `gid=` options.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [waltinator](https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator) who directed me to read man mount.cifs and use uid= and gid= options on mount

This worked a treat

Seán